# Ignore in-text citation/reference while text extraction from docx file using php

Tags: php, regex

We have a .docx file from which we need to extract text using PHP. 
The docx file contains text like:

*Literature had found out that HIV related stigma and discrimination exists among different sectors of life like family, job settings, society and health care settings (1).*

The (1) is denoted as in-text citation with field citation text as

```
>ADDIN CSL_CITATION { 
  "citationItems": [{
    "id": "ITEM-1",
    "itemData": { 
      "URL":"http://www.unaids.org/en",
      "accessed": {
        "date-parts":[["2018","11","4"]]
      },
      "id":"ITEM-1",
      "issued": {
        "date-parts":[["0"]]
      },
      "title":"UNAIDS",
      "type":"webpage"
    },
    "uris":[
      "http://www.mendeley.com/documents/?uuid=fedd4311-1013-3a16-bb82-27566ac11365"
    ]
  }],
  "mendeley": {
    "formattedCitation": "(1)",
    "plainTextFormattedCitation": "(1)",
    "previouslyFormattedCitation":"(1)"
  },
  "properties": {
    "noteIndex":0
  },
  "schema": "https://github.com/citation-style-language/schema/raw/master/csl-citation.json"
}}.
```

We want to remove the field citation text in the text extraction. The result should be plain text without citation. Kindly help us how to remove this field text in PHP.

Comment: Do you mean want to remove json from end of string?

Comment: This in-text citation is coming where ever we have given reference or added field in form of (1)...or   (2) or (3)..or any number. This text is not at the end, it can be anywhere and can occur multiple times in text extraction. We have to remove this in-text citation. Yes, this text is in form of JSON.